# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl' with screenshot utility

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, screenshot, xlib

I am trying to get a screenshot utility to work after porting it from:

```
PyQt4       ->  PyQt5
Python 2.7  ->  Python 3.7
Ubuntu      ->  Windows 7
```

[original code](https://gist.github.com/initbrain/6628609)

[new ported code](https://gist.github.com/frakman1/600c597521ed2cdf9e9ecdb5aaaffc31)

[image]

I changed all the Qt4 references over to Qt5 and got it mostly working except for the `Select Area` function that lets you select an area on the screen by drawing a rectangle. This part fails with the error:

```
resArea: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "screenshot.py", line 318, in <module>
    d = display.Display()
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_xlib-0.24-py3.7.egg\Xlib\display.py", line 89, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_xlib-0.24-py3.7.egg\Xlib\display.py", line 71, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_xlib-0.24-py3.7.egg\Xlib\protocol\display.py", line 85, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_xlib-0.24-py3.7.egg\Xlib\support\connect.py", line 72, in get_display
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_xlib-0.24-py3.7.egg\Xlib\support\connect.py", line 55, in _relative_import
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\frak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\python_xlib-0.24-py3.7.egg\Xlib\support\unix_connect.py", line 31, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

I know that `fcntl` isn't supported on Windows but I think there could be a workaround since I think what the code is trying to do is get some screen dimensions before proceeding.

All the research I've done so far points me to other things like `pyscreenshot` or alternative implementations that only do a full-screen grab but don't have a rectangular selector to select a screen region.

I like this implementation because it shows you a quick preview and options to select an area, adjust delay, hide window and save to file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated